# Using distutils to compile plain C code with unmangled output name

Tags: distutils

I have a little benchmark suite, which compares different approaches to writing and executing some simple toy Python code, mainly for the purpose of illustrating Cython.

One of the approaches I used to have, was to write the test function in pure C, compile it with a C compiler (getting distutils to find and invoke the compiler for me) then load the library into Python with ctypes, and execute the function.

This worked swimmingly until distutils started embedding the python version and the platform in the name of the file it generates.

In the past I could persuade distutils to compile a C source file called `C.c` into a library called `C.so` in the working directory: recent versions of distutils insist on mangling the output name into something of the form `build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6` or (depending on exactly what distutils features I use) some other variaton on that theme.

Is there any way to persuade current versions of distutils to simply call the output `C.so` in the current working directory? (Alternatively, is there some way to reliably and easily tell ctypes where the library produced by distutils resides?)

[Bonus: How can this idea be expressed portably across Linux, OS X and Windows?]

=================================================================

Edit: for completeness, here is how I used to do it successfully in the past:

`pure_C_setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

setup(name="ctypes-test",
      ext_modules = [Extension("C", ["C.c"])])
```

With the above setup file, the command `python pure_C_setup.py install --install-lib=.` *used to* produce `C.so` in the working directory; today it produces `build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/C.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

Comment: from the documentation of ditutils.core.Extension I am not sure if what you are trying to do is possible. I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Not platform, not even compiler independent, but you might be able to use Extension's `extra_link_args` to achieve what you want.

For VCPP 2015:

```
setup(name="ctypes-test",
      ext_modules = [Extension("C", ["C.c"], extra_link_args="/OUT:C.pyd")])
```